# Are these sandals floating due to surface tension or buoyancy?

Tags: fluid-statics, estimation, surface-tension, buoyancy

[image: sandals floating on or in water]

Having an argument. If the sandals are wet (which I think we can assume they are), then they have broken the surface, correct? And if they’ve broken the surface, then that leaves only buoyancy to hold them up.

I reason that they appear to be floating “on” the water because they are incredibly light, foam sandals, and only need to displace a very small amount of water to float.

The angle from which the photo was taken also hides any under-the-surface view of the sandals.

So, is it buoyancy or surface tension? Or both? Or neither? (A higher power?)

Comment: What happens when you release sandals like this from below the surface? If they sink, then it's likely surface tension. If they float, then it's likely buoyancy.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have the sandals. But isn’t it true that if the reason is surface tension and you lift the sandals up the bottoms will be dry? You only get wet if you break the surface, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be buoyancy, since even under very favorable assumptions, the force associated with the surface tension would not be sufficient to keep the sandals from sinking.

Let's assume that the sandals are made out of styrofoam with density $30kg/m^3$ and have dimensions $300mm\times100mm\times10mm$, which translates to about $10g$ weight - not much.

For a sandal to float, the minimum surface tension force would have to be equal to that weight of the sandal, i.e., $\sigma L cos(\theta)=mg$.

With the perimeter, $L=800mm$ $(2\times 300mm + 2\times 100mm)$ and the surface tension coefficient of water $\sigma=73mN/m$, we can find that $cos(\theta)$ would have to be about $1.7$, which says that it must be buoyancy.

Comment: Lovely math! Thanks for confirming my intuition with numbers. I would also add that the choppy surface of the pool would cause a significant increase in the maximum force of the sandals pushing against the water, making surface tension even less plausible.

Comment: Also, do you know if the bottoms of the sandals would come out dry if they had in fact not broken the surface of the water? Or would they be wet?

Comment: @ButtleButkus Dry sounds right to me.

Comment: @V.F. I'm not sure about that. Surface tension is a function mainly of the _cohesion_ of the water, whereas wetting is a function mainly of its _adhesion_ to the sandal. Those are two independent variables, as far as I know.

Comment: @probably_someone "The degree of wetting (wettability) is determined by a force balance between adhesive and cohesive forces." Wikipedia.

Comment: @V.F. Okay, sure, wetting depends on both, but "The cohesive forces between liquid molecules are responsible for the phenomenon known as surface tension," (from HyperPhysics) so I still maintain that it's possible to not break the surface and still get wet (because adhesion plays a major role only in wetting).

Comment: @probably_someone if something is wet then it is coated in water molecules. How would a wet surface not break the water’s surface? You couldn’t pour a bucketful of water onto a pools surface, it would immediately become one with the pool water.

Comment: @ButtleButkus In the same way that, when you get waxed, the wax does not break the skin, but is still covered in skin cells when it is removed. Or if you step in a puddle of glue, you don't have to break the surface of the glue for the bottom of your foot to be covered in it when you step off. And you're correct about pouring a bucketful of water into a pool; the key here is that two _different_ (i.e. distinguishable) materials are involved.

Comment: @probably_someone so in essence the wetness is just water sticking to the object. If you coat your hand in a hydrophobic powder, you can dip your hand into the water without it getting wet. Are you then breaking the surface, or does the surface mold itself around the shape of your hand, not breaking? Do water striders’ feet get wet?

Comment: @ButtleButkus I have a feeling this depends on what your precise definition of "surface" is. If your definition of surface is such that a hydrophobic material never breaks the surface, then one might argue that _no material_ ever breaks the surface, because the surface molds around them, too, it just sticks to them better.

Comment: @probably_someone right, but then stickiness and “breaking the surface” become synonymous and we get back to my first thought, which was that “if it’s wet, it’s broken the surface.” I don’t know!